# Redirecting from Controller doesn't work in CodeIgniter 3 (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, model-view-controller

at the moment I have to create a project with the PHP framework CodeIgniter. Everything is working properly, except for `redirect()`. If I call a `redirect()` after I inserted something to the database the project doesn't redirect to the index page. I already set the URL Helper to autoload and I configured the Base Path.

Controller:

```
<?php
    class Modules extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->session->set_userdata('site_language', 'german');
        }

        public function index($search = '') {
            $data['modules'] = $this->module_model->get_modules($search);

            $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
            $this->load->view('modules/index.php', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
        }

        public function create() {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
                $this->load->view('modules/new.php');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
            }
            else {
                $this->module_model->create_module();
                redirect('modules/index');
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php
    class Module_model extends CI_Model {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_modules($search) {
            // TODO ~> Suche implementieren

            $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
            $query = $this->db->get('modules');

            return $query->result_array();
        }

        public function create_module() {
            $active = $this->input->post('active');

            if (!empty($active)) {
                $active = 1;
            }
            else {
                $active = 0;
            }
            $data = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'), 'active' => $active);
        }
    }
```

Base Path:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projects/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME_004/';
```

I'd be very happy if someone could help me. :)

Comment: how are you calling the controller function `create()`?

Comment: I'm calling it via ``<?php echo form_open('modules/create', $formAttributes) ?>`` and the data is inserted into the database absolutely fine, but after this the ``redirect('modules/index');`` doesn't work so the programm stays at a blank page.

This is the declaration of ``$formAttributes``: ``$formAttributes = array('class' => 'default-form');``

Comment: did you autoload the url helper?

Comment: also redirect needs a leading `/`: `redirect('/modules/index');`

Comment: The URL Helper is loaded ``$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');``. I tried it was a leading ``/``, but it didn't change something.

Comment: last try: does `http://localhost/projects/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME_004/modules/index` show something?

Comment: Yes, the index page works perfect. After I inserted something to the database the URL keeps stading at ``http://localhost/projects/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME_004/modules/create``.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of help from a friend we solved the problem with passing another parameter with the redirect method. The working redirect looks like this: `redirect('modules', 'refresh');`

Sadly I still don't know why a normal redirect doesn't work.

Comment: check file application\system\core\helpers\uri_helper.php to see the difference of redirect with and without refresh (~line 517)

Answer (score 0):

well if you still courious why normal redirect doesnt work...try put ob_start(); at the very first line of your code after <?php tag...maybe it can work...

Answer (score 0):

Mate. Define your link in routes.php in the application config folder. That’s why the redirect won’t work.

Comment: Example user defined routes :

Comment: $route[‘myLink’] = “myControllerName/myFynction”;

Comment: If I put ``$route['modules'] = 'modules/index';`` into config/routes.php it's still not working.

Comment: My friend. Do not put index, just put the controller name in the 'modules/index';
If you put only 'modules'; it will automatically read the index function.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't change anything.